# Derivative of the equilibrium of a zero-sum game

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, game-theory, simplex, nash-equilibrium

Let $n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\triangle n$ be the $n$-dimensional standard simplex. Let $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times n_2}$ be the payoff matrix of a zero-sum [normal-form game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-form_game). Then

\begin{align}
N_1(G) &= \operatorname*{argmax}_{s_1 \in \triangle n_1} \min_{s_2 \in \triangle n_2} G \cdot s_1 \cdot s_2 \\
N_2(G) &= \operatorname*{argmin}_{s_2 \in \triangle n_2} \max_{s_1 \in \triangle n_1} G \cdot s_1 \cdot s_2
\end{align}

are the maxmin and minmax strategies for each player. $N_1$ and $N_2$ are differentiable [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere). How can I obtain the partial derivatives

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial N_1(G)}{\partial G} \qquad
\frac{\partial N_2(G)}{\partial G}
\end{align}

in terms of $G$, $N_1(G)$, and $N_2(G)$? I suspect [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation) and the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) might be helpful. I know that the derivative of the equilibrium *value* [is](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221719309312) (see page 3, column 1)

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial N(G)}{\partial G}
&= \frac{\partial G \cdot N_1(G) \cdot N_2(G)}{\partial G} \\
&= \frac{\partial G : N_1(G) \otimes N_2(G)}{\partial G} \\
&= N_1(G) \otimes N_2(G)
\end{align}

where $:$ is the [double dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_dyadic) and $\otimes$ is the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). Assume the solution is not degenerate.

Comment: You notation of vec-vec dot products and mat-vec products is nonstandard and very confusing. For example, $G.s_1.s_2$ should be written $s_1^T G s_2$.

Comment: To solve your problem, I think a combo of *Danskin's Theorem* and the *Implicit-Function Theorem* should do the trick. Will find some time to write this down.

Answer (score 1):

If the game with matrix $\ G\ $ is non-degenerate, then there is a unique square submatrix $\ A\ $ of $\ G\ $ such that the matrix $\ \pmatrix{A&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}\ $ is non-singular, and the corresponding subvectors, $\ \overline{N_1(G)}, 
\overline{N_2(G)}\ $, of the minimax strategies $\ N_1(G), N_2(G)\ $, and the value, $\ N(G)\ $ satisfy
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{A&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}\pmatrix{\overline{N_2(G)}\\-N(G)}&= \pmatrix{\mathbb{0}\\1}\\
\pmatrix{A^\top&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}\pmatrix{\overline{N_1(G)}\\-N(G)}&= \pmatrix{\mathbb{0}\\1}
\end{align}
Differentiating the first of these equations with respect to $\ a_{ij}\ $ gives
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{E_{ij}&\mathbb{0}\\\mathbb{0}^\top&0} \pmatrix{\overline{ N_2(G)}\\-N(G)}+ \pmatrix{A&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}\pmatrix{\frac{\partial \overline{ N_2(G)}}{\partial a_{ij}}\\-\frac{\partial N(G)}{\partial a_{ij}}}&= \pmatrix{\mathbb{0}\\0}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ E_{ij}\ $ is the matrix whose $\ ij^\text{th}\ $ entry is $1$, and all of whose other entries are $0$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{\frac{\partial \overline{ N_2(G)}}{\partial a_{ij}}\\-\frac{\partial N(G)}{\partial a_{ij}}}&= -\pmatrix{A&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}^{-1} \pmatrix{E_{ij}&\mathbb{0}\\\mathbb{0}^\top&0} \pmatrix{\overline{ N_2(G)}\\-N(G)}\\
&=  -\pmatrix{A&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}^{-1} \pmatrix{E_{ij}&\mathbb{0}\\\mathbb{0}^\top&0} \pmatrix{A&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}^{-1} \pmatrix{\mathbb{0}\\1}\ ,
\end{align}
and similarly
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{\partial \overline{ N_1(G)}}{\partial a_{ij}}\\-\frac{\partial N(G)}{\partial a_{ij}}}=   -\pmatrix{A^\top&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}^{-1} \pmatrix{E_{ji}&\mathbb{0}\\\mathbb{0}^\top&0} \pmatrix{A^\top&\mathbb{1}\\\mathbb{1}^\top&0}^{-1} \pmatrix{\mathbb{0}\\1}\  
$$
For entries $\ g_{ij}\ $ of $\ G\ $ lying outside the matrix $\ A\ $, $\ \frac{\partial N_1(G)}{\partial g_{ij}}=$$\frac{\partial N_2(G)}{\partial g_{ij}}=$$\mathbb{0}\ $.

Comment: How can one determine $A$?

Comment: By solving the game (with the Simplex algorithm, for instance). It's the submatrix of  $\ G\ $ whose first indices $\ i\ $ are those for which $\ \left[GN_2(G)\right]_i=N(G)\ $ and whose second indices $\ j\ $ are those for which $\ \left[G^\top N_1(G)\right]_j=N(G)\ $.