# Derivative of the solution of a linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, partial-derivative, linear-programming, constraints

Let $x^\star$ be a solution of the linear program
\begin{align}
\text{maximize} &\quad c \cdot x \\
\text{subject to} &\quad A \cdot x \leq b
\end{align}
How can one compute the derivatives of $x^\star$ with respect to the linear program parameters?
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x^\star}{\partial A} \qquad
\frac{\partial x^\star}{\partial b} \qquad
\frac{\partial x^\star}{\partial c}
\end{align}

where derivatives are interpreted in the [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) sense, e.g. $$\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial A} \right)_{ijk} = \frac{\partial x_i}{ \partial A_{jk}}$$

I suspect the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) might be useful here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as sensitivity analysis.  If you have a non-degenerate optimal basic feasible solution, it is relatively simple to find derivatives of the optimal BFS or the optimal objective value  with respect to changes in b or c.  Changes to A can also be analyzed, but this is somewhat more complicated.

If the optimal BFS is degenerate, these derivatives may not exist.

See just about any textbook on linear programming.

Here's a brief explanation.

First, put your LP into standard form by adding slack variables to eliminate the inequality constraints:

$\min c^{T}x$

subject to

$Ax=b$

$x \geq 0$

Here $A$ is a matrix of size $m$ by $n$ with rank $m$.

If there is a unique and non-degenerate optimal basic feasible solution, Then the variables in $x$ can be split up into a vector $x_{B}$ of $m$ basic variables and a vector $x_{N}$ of $n-m$ nonbasic variables.

Let $B$ be the matrix obtaining by taking the columns of $A$ that are in the basis and $A_{N}$ consist of the remaining columns of $A$.   Similarly, let $c_{B}$ and $c_{N}$ be the coefficients in $c$ corresponding to basic and nonbasic variables.

You can now write the problem as

$\min c_{B}^{T}x_{B}+c_{N}^{T}x_{N}$

subject to

$Bx_{B}+A_{N}x_{N}=b$

$x \geq 0$.

In the optimal basic solution, we solve for $x_{B}$  and write the problem as

$\min c_{B}^{T}B^{-1}b + (c_{N}^{T}-c_{B}^{T}B^{-1}A_{N})x_{N} $

subject to

$x_{B}=B^{-1}b-B^{-1}A_{N}x_{N} $

$x \geq 0.$

An important optimality condition that the simplex method ensures is that

$r_{N}=c_{N}-c_{B}^{T}B^{-1}A_{N} \geq 0.$

If the solution is also dual non-degenerate, then $r_{N}>0$.  We'll need to assume that as well.

In the optimal basic solution, we set all of the variables in $x_{N}$ to $x_{N}^{*}=0$ and get the values of the basic variables from $x_{B}^{*}=B^{-1}b$.  By assumption, this optimal basic feasible solution is non-degenerate, meaning that $B^{-1}b$ is strictly greater than 0. Small changes to $b$ won't change $r_{N}$ and won't violate $x_{B} \geq 0$, so the solution will remain optimal after small changes to $b$.

Now, it should be clear that

$\frac{\partial x_{B}^{*}}{\partial b}=B^{-1}$

and

$\frac{\partial x_{N}^{*}}{\partial b}=0.$

Small changes in $c$ won't change $x_{B}$ at all, and will not lose $r_{N} \geq 0$.  Thus the solution will remain optimal, and $x_{B}$ won't change, although the optimal objective value will change.  Thus

$\frac{\partial x_{B}^{*}}{\partial c}=0$

and

$\frac{\partial x_{N}^{*}}{\partial c}=0.$

If the assumptions of non-degeneracy are violated then these derivatives may simply not exist!

In a similar way, you can analyze changes in $A_{N}$ or in $B$.

This stuff is discussed in V. Chvatal's *Linear Programming* among many other textbooks on the subject.

Comment: Do you know of a specific reference that addresses partial derivatives of the attained solution with respect to the parameters? I only found ones addressing partial derivatives of the attained value.

Comment: I've expanded the answer including a reference and showing you how to find derivatives of the optimal solution with respect to changes in $b$ and $c$.

Comment: For [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457832/derivative-of-the-equilibrium-of-a-zero-sum-game), I formulated it as a linear program and tried to use the equations given in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00443.pdf (in particular, equation 5), but numerical tests seem to indicate I'm getting the wrong answer. It corresponds to derivatives with respect to $A$ in this context. Do you by any chance know what the correct expression is (for the derivatives of the strategies with respect to the payoff matrix)?

Comment: The Arxiv paper that you've linked to concerns itself with quadratic programming, not linear programming.  My answer above deals only with linear programming.  If you have a question about the Arxiv paper, plesae write it up as a separate question and include the reference.

Comment: Doesn't $Q=0$ (letting the quadratic term be zero) recover the linear case?

Comment: Yes, $Q=0$ gets you back to the linear case.  However, it's absolutely true that the optimal solution to an LP is not a smooth function of the data when the optimal solution is degenerate.  This is mentioned at the top of page two of the supplementary material (the authors state that this occurs on a set of measure 0, but LP's and QP's in real applications aren't randomly distributed and often are degenerate.)  If you've got a degenerate optimal solution, then all bets are off.  You should update your question to provide more context.

Comment: Right. The solution is assumed to not be degenerate.