# Second-order envelope theorem for linear programming

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, inverse-function-theorem

Consider parameterized linear programming $V(\theta) = \max_x \langle c(\theta),x\rangle$ s.t. $A(\theta)x\leq b(\theta)$, $x\geq 0$. Let's also assume $c,A,b$ are infinitely differentiable with respect to $\theta$.

It is known (the envelope theorem) that under suitable conditions (one sufficient condition is that the set of binding constraints does not change for all $\theta\in B_\delta(\theta_0)=\{\theta: \|\theta-\theta_0\|\leq\delta\}$ for some $\delta>0$) the objective $V$ is differentiable in $\theta$ for $\theta\in \mathrm{Int}B_\delta(\theta_0)$ and furthermore
$$
\nabla_\theta  V(\theta) = \langle\nabla c(\theta), x^*(\theta)\rangle-\langle\lambda^* (\theta) ,\nabla b(\theta) -\partial_\theta A(\theta)x^*(\theta)\rangle,
$$
where $x^*(\theta)$ is the optimal solution at $\theta$ and $\lambda^*(\theta)$ is the optimal Lagriangian multipler for all constraints $A(\theta)x\leq b(\theta)$.

My question is: under the condition that the set of binding constraints does not change for all $\theta\in B_\delta(\theta_0)=\{\theta: \|\theta-\theta_0\|\leq\delta\}$ for some $\delta>0$, is $V$ also twice differentiable in $\theta$? If so, can we compute
$$
\nabla_{\theta\theta^\top}^2V(\theta)
$$
for all $\theta\in\mathrm{Int}B_\delta(\theta_0)$? If the hessian doesn't necessarily exist, what additional conditions should be imposed?

While a general solution to the problem is certainly welcome, for my particular application it is sufficient to handle the case when $c$ is a constant function and both $A(\theta),b(\theta)$ are linear functions of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

I can give a partial answer for the case c linear and A, b constant, and hopefully this also helps for the other cases.

I assume this post is correct: [Derivative of the solution of a linear program](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460124/derivative-of-the-solution-of-a-linear-program).

For $c(\theta)=M\theta$ linear and A, b constant, $\nabla_\theta V(\theta)$ is just $M x^*(\theta)$. Now the post referenced above says that $\frac{\partial}{\partial c} x^*=0$. So the Hessian you are looking for is 0.

I guess you have the same thing when b is linear and A, c are constant, just by looking at the dual problem. For when A varies, the post referenced above mentions that this kind of sensitivity analysis is still possible, but I don't know beyond that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer after a long time. It is known that if only c and b vary (linearly) then the hessian is zero. That's the foundation of most LP resolve papers. The particular setting in my application is A varying with theta making everything difficult. The Hessian most likely won't be zero. Anyway, appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Let for concision $V = V(\theta), \partial V = \nabla_\theta V(\theta)$ and $c = c(\theta), \partial c = \nabla_\theta c(\theta)$ and similarly for $A, b$, as well as $x = x^*(\theta), \partial x = \nabla_\theta x^*(\theta)$ and similarly for $\lambda$.
Also let
$\partial^2_{ij} V = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta_i \theta_j} V(\theta) = \left[ \nabla^2_{\theta \theta^\top} V(\theta) \right]_{ij}$
and similarly for $\partial^2_{ij} c, A$ and $b$.
If indices get confusing just think of the case $\theta$ scalar.

As you wrote,
$$
\partial V = (\partial c)^\top x - \lambda^\top \left[ \partial b - (\partial A) x \right],
$$
so by differentiating again $\partial_i V$ with respect to $\theta_j$,
\begin{align}
\partial^2_{ij} V &= (\partial^2_{ij} c)^\top x + (\partial_i c)^\top (\partial_j x) - (\partial_j \lambda)^\top \left[ \partial_i b - (\partial_i A) x \right] - \lambda^\top \left[ \partial^2_{ij} b - (\partial^2_{ij} A) x - (\partial_i A) (\partial_j x) \right] \\
&= (\partial^2_{ij} c)^\top x
- \lambda^\top \partial^2_{ij} b
+ \lambda^\top (\partial^2_{ij} A) x
+ \left[ \partial_i c - (\partial_i A)^\top \lambda \right]^\top (\partial_j x)
- (\partial_j \lambda)^\top \left[ \partial_i b - (\partial_i A) x \right].
\end{align}

To compute $\partial_j x$ and $\partial_j \lambda$, differentiate the optimality conditions with respect to $\theta_j$:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
Ax=b \\
\lambda^\top A = -c^\top
\end{cases}
&\implies
\begin{cases}
(\partial A) x + A (\partial x) = \partial b \\
\lambda^\top (\partial A) + (\partial \lambda)^\top A = -(\partial c)^\top
\end{cases} \\
&\implies
\begin{cases}
\partial x = A^\dagger \left[ \partial b - (\partial A) x \right] + r_x \\
(\partial \lambda)^\top = - \left[ \partial c + (\partial A)^\top \lambda \right]^\top A^\dagger + r_\lambda^\top
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $r_x \in \ker(A)$, $r_\lambda \in \ker(A^\top)$ and $A^\dagger$ is pseudo-inverse.

By substituting you get an explicit formula for the Hessian you are looking for:
\begin{align}
\partial^2_{ij} V
&= (\partial^2_{ij} c)^\top x
- \lambda^\top \partial^2_{ij} b
+ \lambda^\top (\partial^2_{ij} A) x \\
&~~ + \left[ \partial_i c - (\partial_i A)^\top \lambda \right]^\top A^\dagger \left[ \partial_j b - (\partial_j A) x \right] \\
&~~
+ \left[ \partial_j c + (\partial_j A)^\top \lambda \right]^\top A^\dagger \left[ \partial_i b - (\partial_i A) x \right].
\end{align}
The $r_x, r_\lambda$ disappear because the calculation above also shows that
$\left[ (\partial_i c) - \lambda^\top (\partial_i A) \right]^\top = (\partial_i \lambda)^\top A$
resp.
$\left[ \partial_i b - (\partial_i A) x \right] = A (\partial_i x)$.